# Creating a drag-and-drop designer UI with JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I want to create a web based UI which can do some basic drag drop and stuff. I am going to use it for I want to allow users to create some small certificates . Users can add text at places they want or upload images and than drop it at required places. I will than want to store those Images , text positions and width in a database based on which I will later generate a PDF file .

Is there any better approach some one suggest ? Also is there any existing UI plugin which can make this easier ?

Comment: I hope these will help you http://threedubmedia.com/demo/drag/ you will be knowing jquery UI plugin anyway http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

Answer (score 1):

jQueryUI's `draggable` and `droppable` can make this easy. Draggable requires 0 effort, an Droppable gives you the exact coordinates. [See their examples](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable) [in the jQueryUI Site](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable).